# Rule of distribution

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

If random variable x gets $\alpha$ independent draws from distribution G(x,t) and $\beta$ draws from another distribution H(x,t).

Question:

1. Does r.v can gets draw from two distribution function?
2. Can I write them as $\alpha G(x,t) + \beta H(x,t)$ or $G(x,t)^\alpha H(x,t)^\beta $ ?